# Something like Bootstrap collapsible with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a small app and I'm using AngularJS. Inside the app I need a collapsible element and using Twitter Bootstrap would be as easy as adding the library and some tags on my target element and the trigger.

But I'm trying not to load other external libraries like bootstrap or any other, so I was trying to achieve the same behavior with Angular :

```
$scope.collapse = function(target) {

        var that = angular.element(document).find(target),

            transitioned = {
                'WebkitTransition' : 'webkitTransitionEnd',
                'MozTransition'    : 'transitionend',
                'OTransition'      : 'oTransitionEnd otransitionend',
                'msTransition'     : 'MSTransitionEnd',
                'transition'       : 'transitionend'
            },

            _transitioned = transitioned[ Modernizr.prefixed('transition') ],

            height = that.outerHeight(true);

        if (angular.element(that).hasClass("in")) {
            that.height(0);
        } else {
            that.height(height);
        };

        that.on(_transitioned, function() {
            that.toggleClass("in");
        });
    };
```

As you can see I'm trying to transition the height ( as the element has a transition on the height ) and in the end just add the class `in`. But that isn't working very well because if I'm listening on the transition end it will trigger on any transition end inside that element.

I would need some help with this, how can I rewrite the bootstrap collapsible just with angular ? I don't need the events that bootstrap has like on `shown`, `hidden` or `show`, `hide`, I just need to trigger a simple collapse of the element with transition and keep my elements height dynamic ( I don't want a fixed height, otherwise I would just use CSS to achieve the collapse ). I just need to be pinpointed in the right direction :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like you want to just collapse something with CSS3 transitions?

Well, you can do that, but the controller is the wrong place to be doing that. You should do that with directives or in a custom directive. Fortunately, you can do it with the Angular native directives, such as ng-class.

HTML:

```html
<button ng-click="open = !open">Toggle</button>    
<div ng-class="{ showMe: open }" class="collapsable">
  <h3>This should collapse</h3>
</div>
```

And most importantly, your CSS:

```css
  .collapsable {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;
    transition: height 1s;
    -webkit-transition: height 1s;        
    -moz-transition: height 1s;        
    -o-transition: height 1s;         
  }
  .collapsable.showMe {
    height: 100px;
  }
```

[And here is a plunker of it working.](http://plnkr.co/edit/PbX9hSCgaBl4GsbtqZ1U?p=preview)

Important to note, CSS3 transitions will not work in all browsers. Particularly in IE.  In the end, I think you'd probably be better off using a plugin that someone else already made, and then leveraging it in a custom directive that watched some boolean value.

I hope that helps.

---

**EDIT**

`height: auto` does not work with CSS Transitions (at least as of the time of this post). So, this is why you'll really want to use someone else's plugin, rather than reinvent the wheel. Even if it's just JQuery's animate() method.  The psuedo-code for rolling your own directive would be something like so: (presuming you're using JQuery)

```js
app.directive('collapseWhen', function () {
   return function(scope, elem, attr) {
     scope.$watch(attr.collapseWhen, function(val) {
        var clone = elem.clone().appendTo('body');
        var h = clone.height();
        clone.remove();
        scope.animate({ height: (val ? h : 0) + 'px' }, 1000);
     }
   }
});
```

and then you'd use it like:

```
<button ng-click="foo = !foo">Toggle</button>
<div collapse-when="foo">
```

Again, the above is *psuedo-code*, I have no idea if it will work or not, it's just to give you an idea to follow if you *really* want to roll your own.

Comment: As I mentioned in my description, `collapsable.showMe { height: 100px; }`, the height should be `auto` so I can have my content height dynamic, because more elements could be appended afterwords ...

Comment: That is why you'll want to use someone else's plugin. What you'll need to do is check the height of your inner content with javascript, and then set that height with CSS on the fly. `auto` doesn't work with CSS transitions in any browser I know of.

Comment: Wasn't that what I just said in the description ? That having auto height wouldn't work in this case when I want css transitions. So that is why I was trying to set the height first and then add the `in` class which has `height : auto`. Just that using on transitioned end won't work. Neither getting the height of the element will work since the class `collapse` set's it to `0px`. So that is why I'm asking here if there is a way of doing it without the events that bootstrap has and only have the collapse.

Comment: No reason to get snippy. I'm trying to help you.

Comment: You'll need to take a copy of the element and measure it's height to set it with CSS. I've added some demo code to give you an idea.

Comment: I'm not :) I never do :P I was just trying to make myself understood, I'm not that good at explaining :)

Answer (score 2):

If i understand the questions, my solution is to use angular $animateCss. Here there are the docs and examples https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate/service/$animateCss

With $animateCss service you can create your own animation using ngAnimate. This is an example of the angular module. The demo is in the link below

```
var AppModule = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate'])
  .controller('collapseCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.btn1 = $scope.btn2 = $scope.btn3 = false;
  }]).animation('.my-collapse', ['$animateCss', function($animateCss) {
    return {
      enter: function(element, doneFn) {
        var height = element[0].offsetHeight;
        return $animateCss(element, {
          from: {
            height: '0px',
            overflow: 'hidden'
          },
          to: {
            height: height + 'px'
          },
          cleanupStyles: true,
          duration: 0.3 // one second
        });
      },
      leave: function(element, doneFn) {
        var height = element[0].offsetHeight;
        return $animateCss(element, {
          to: {
            height: '0px',
            overflow: 'hidden'
          },
          from: {
            height: height + 'px'
          },
          cleanupStyles: true,
          duration: 0.3 // one second
        });
      }
    };
  }]);
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/DjU1A2vmiBB1dYXjkiN1

Answer (score 0):

Roland, take a look at [Bootstrap Project](http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap) from angular-ui team.

Comment: I already know about it ;) The accordion doesn't fit my needs, I have to be able to trigger the collapse from anywhere in the markup, in which case the bootstrap project has a directive that covers that but you cannot have your trigger outside of the directive context